# MPDF create read only pdf file?

Tags: php, pdf, edit, readonly, mpdf

I'm using mpdf to download an existing file like this-

```
$mpdf->Output('my_filename.pdf','D');
```

I need the file downloaded to be read only. Right now the downloaded files can be opened in word and edited, I wish to avoid that.

**TL;DR** :
I'm downloading an existing file from my system which my clients can edit by opening in word, need to avoid that.I can't have password protection for the files(client requirement)

Comment: UPDATE : used SetWatermarkImage to put image over the pdf pages but I don't think it serves the purpose. Any other solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SetProtection()` function as described [here](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html).

```
$filename = 'filename.pdf';
$html = 'Testing PDF protection.';
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-P');
$mpdf->SetProtection(array());
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output($filename,'D');
```

Comment: Thanx, but need something not dealing with passwords.

Comment: keeping the password parameter blank does it! thanx..ans accepted ;)